# Como solucionar error Add-Migration connectionstring null

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core, code-first

[image: error frecuente]

El mensaje me sale igual a pesar que vi otras preguntas similares.Más adelante pongo otras imagenes para que vean como esta el appsettings y context.

appsettings.json.

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=RACPAVI\\RAC; Initial Catalog=WEBAPIPAIS; UserID=sa; Password=qpwoei"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "Debug": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

ApplicationDbContext.cs

```
public class ApplicationDbContext: DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
    {
    }
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        :base(options)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
        IConfigurationRoot config = builder.Build();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
    }
    public DbSet<Pais> Paises { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Provincia> Provincias { get; set; }
}
public class DesignTimeDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
        var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        return new ApplicationDbContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

Comment: En el Package Manager Console, verifica que tienes como default project al proyecto que  contiene a tu dbcontext. Aparte si ya tienes la cadena de coneccion por defecto en el archivo de configuracion no es necesario volver a asignarlo por codigo

Comment: Te sugiero que edites esa pregunta, la idea es mejorarla compartiendo el código directamente no screenshots. Asi recibirás mas atención.

Comment: gracias por las sugerencias juanK.

Comment: Elcainas, si verifiqué que esta por default en mi unico proyecto,cuando lo hice.

Answer (score 2):

En esta línea no debes poner la cadena de conexión completa , solo el nombre  de la misma en el archivo de configuración. Y en el archivo de configuración respeta los espacios y de la la cadena de conexión en el mismo renglón.

```
OptionBuilder.UseSQLServer(config.GetconnectionString("Defaultconnection"));
```

Verifica que estás llevando bien el proceso de carga del archivo de configuración

```
IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                     .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true,
                                   reloadOnChange: true);


IConfigurationRoot configurationRoot = configurationBuilder.Build();
```

y luego

```
var cs = configurationRoot.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
configurationBuilder.UseSqlServer(cs);
```

Comment: gracias JuanK lo intente pero sigo con el problema.

Comment: @ARobert he actualizado la respuesta , espero te funcione.

Answer (score 0):

¿Por que primero llamas al evento del padre y con el parámetro y luego lo cargas ?  `base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);` de hecho no deberías llamarlo aquí.

```
 protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
        IConfigurationRoot config = builder.Build();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

    }
```

Comment: gracias pero sigo con el problema igual

Answer (score 0):

invoca la conexión  a través de  una  variable

var connection = @"Data Source=RACPAVI\RAC; Initial Catalog=WEBAPIPAIS; UserID=sa; Password=qpwoei"
services.AddDbContext(option => option.UseSqlServer(connection));