# Presento el siguiente error: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, identity

Buen día,

Preseton el siguiente error en .NetCore 3.1, al intentar correr el comando en la consola: add-migration InitialCommit, el error es: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString').

El código del appsettings es:

```
{
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "DefaultConnection": "Persist Security info=False;User Id=sa;password=holamundo;Initial Catalog=simoau_;Data Source=jonathan;Connection Timeout -100000"
},
```

}

Y el código en el startup está de la siguiente manera:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();

    }
```

Por último, el archivo .csproj cuenta con los ítems de la siguiente forma:

```
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.19" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.19" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="3.1.19" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.19" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.19">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration" Version="3.1.5" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.5" />
```

Agrego el código del DBContext:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Simoau_TF_.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Agradezco cualquier guía que me puedan brindar

Comment: Aqui hay una pregunta similar a la tuya con respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/201148/como-solucionar-error-add-migration-connectionstring-null?rq=1

Comment: Gracias, pero valido las soluciones que le brindan y ninguna me aplica

Comment: podrias mostrar lo que tienes en tu clase de `ApplicationDbContext` e intentar con esta forma en tu linea de conexion
`"DefaultConnection": "Server=tuservidor; Initial Catalog=simoau_; User Id=sa;Password=holamundo;"`

Comment: Es mejor que edites la pregunta, igual no veo que estes agregando ninguna tabla

Comment: Hola, editada y no, aún no agregado ninguna tabla, en teoría  sería el paso a seguir luego de que permita la conexión

Comment: @JonathanCórdobaDelaHoz yo acabo de replicar tu proyecto, solo que lo use en localhost usando net core web app y no tuve ningun problema, hay alguna manera de poder resolverlo en tu maquina, tienes algun contacto, y otra cosa , en la version de `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` cambialo a `Version="3.1.19"` , todas las versiones deben ser la misma